# Visual Studio 2019 .NET VB web application SQL syntax error

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, web-applications

I want to perform a query search with two user inputs from a textbox and display the result on a Viewgrid but I'm having problems with the parameters I want to insert in the query and I get the following error:

> ExecQuery error:
> Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '.'.
> Must declare the variable '@H'.

Did I implement a incorrect function or am I doing this in an incorrect manner or if I'm simply trying to fill the viewgrid incorrectly? I'll appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

This is my `SQLControl` code:

```vb
Public Class SQLControl
    ReadOnly DBCon As New SqlConnection()
    Private DBCmd As SqlCommand

    'DB Data
    Public DBDA As SqlDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As DataTable

    'Query Parameters
    Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)

    'Query Statistics
    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String

    'This generates a blank sqlclient class with the deafult connection string
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    'Allow connection string override
    Public Sub New(connectionString As String)
        DBCon = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    End Sub

    'Execute Query Sub
    Public Sub ExecQuery(query As String)
        'Reset Query Stats
        RecordCount = 0
        Exception = ""

        Try

            DBCon.Open()

            'Create DB Command
            DBCmd = New SqlCommand(query, DBCon)

            'Load Params Into DB Command
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))

            'Clear Param List
            Params.Clear()

            'Execute Command & Fill Dataset
            DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Capture Error
            Exception = "ExecQuery Error: " & vbNewLine & ex.Message
        Finally
            'Close Connection
            If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Add Params
    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub

    'Error Checking 
    Public Function HasException(Optional Report As Boolean = False) As Boolean
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Exception) Then Return False
        If Report = True Then MsgBox(Exception, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Exception:")
        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

This is the button where I execute the query:

```
Protected Sub ExecuteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExecuteButton.Click

    If StoreIDTextbox.Text.Length <= 0 Then
        MsgBox("Invalid input. Please enter both Store ID and Transaction ID.")
    End If

    If TransactionIDTextbox.Text.Length <= 0 Then
        MsgBox("Invalid input. Please enter both Store ID and Transaction ID.")
    End If

    SQL.AddParam("@H.Str_ID", Integer.Parse(StoreIDTextbox.Text))
    SQL.AddParam("@H.Tran_ID", Integer.Parse(TransactionIDTextbox.Text))

    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT H.Emp_ID, H.Cust_ID, D.*
          FROM Transaction_Header H  
          INNER JOIN LN_Detail L ON (H.Str_ID = L.Str_ID AND H.Rgst_ID = L.Rgst_ID AND H.Tran_ID = L.Tran_ID)
          INNER Join LN_Discount D ON (L.Str_ID = D.Str_ID AND L.Rgst_ID = D.Rgst_ID AND L.Tran_ID = D.Tran_ID AND L.Tran_LN_Num = D.Tran_LN_Num)
          WHERE H.Str_ID = @H.Str_ID AND H.Tran_ID = @H.Tran_ID")

    If SQL.HasException(True) Then Exit Sub

    GridView1.DataSource = SQL.DBDT

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `.` from the parameter name. Also, and perhaps even more importantly, do not re-use a single connection object: create (New) it when it is needed and then .Dispose() of it.

Comment: You would probably be better off using [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/) because it does a lot of the behind-the-scenes code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class:
I have moved your database objects to the methods where they are used so they can be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks do this for you.

If you need a record count, it is available from `DataTable.Rows.Count`

If you do not plan to handle exceptions within your class, then don't put the `Try...End Try` there. One of the points of having a data access class is to separate the user interface from the data source. Showing a message box in you data access class hard codes a link to the user interface. Your class shouldn't be tied to a desktop app in Windows that can display a message box. Suppose you want to use you class in a web app. You would have to rewrite the class. I put the `Try...End Try` in the button event (user interface code) where you can display a message box.

I left the parameter handling alone because it does protect your database from Sql injection. However it is not the best way to handle parameters for Sql Server. ADO.net must guess at the datatype and it can guess wrong. For example, ADO.net sees a string as the value for a parameter. It assigns `NVarChar` as the datatype but the field in the database may actually be a `VarChar`. Now Sql Server must temporarily expand the field to an `NVarChar` to search for your parameter. You can see how inefficient that is. Then consider a number value of 6. Is it an integer or some type of float?

In the button code I used `Integer.TryParse` to validate the user input adding an `Exit Sub` to allow the user to correct the error.

Apparently the real problem was as commented by @Andrew Morton. I changed the names of the parameters. Many times joins are from primary key to foreign key but perhaps you have composite keys.

Data Access Class

```vb
Public Class SQLControl

    Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

    'Query Parameters
    Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)

    'This generates a blank sqlclient class with the deafult connection string
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    'Allow connection string override
    Public Sub New(connectionString As String)
        ConStr = connectionString
    End Sub

    'Execute Query Sub
    Public Function ExecQuery(query As String) As DataTable
        'Params.Clear()
        Dim DBDT = New DataTable
        Using DBCon As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                DBCmd As New SqlCommand(query, DBCon)
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))
            Params.Clear()
            DBCon.Open()
            DBDT.Load(DBCmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        Return DBDT
    End Function

    'Add Params
    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub

End Class
```

User Interface Code

```
Private Sql As New SQLControl("Your connection string")

Protected Sub ExecuteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExecuteButton.Click
    Dim StoreID As Integer
    Dim TransID As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(StoreIDTextbox.Text, StoreID) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid input. Please enter both Store ID and Transaction ID.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not Integer.TryParse(TransactionIDTextbox.Text, TransID) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid input. Please enter both Store ID and Transaction ID.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Sql.AddParam("@Str_ID", StoreID)
    Sql.AddParam("@Tran_ID", TransID)
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Try
        dt = Sql.ExecQuery("SELECT H.Emp_ID, H.Cust_ID, D.*
      FROM Transaction_Header H  
      INNER JOIN LN_Detail L ON (H.Str_ID = L.Str_ID AND H.Rgst_ID = L.Rgst_ID AND H.Tran_ID = L.Tran_ID)
      INNER Join LN_Discount D ON (L.Str_ID = D.Str_ID AND L.Rgst_ID = D.Rgst_ID AND L.Tran_ID = D.Tran_ID AND L.Tran_LN_Num = D.Tran_LN_Num)
      WHERE H.Str_ID = @Str_ID AND H.Tran_ID = @Tran_ID")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```